# How to pass ImageView betweenActivity and Fragment?

Tags: android

How can I pass my ImageView between Fragment and Activity?
In one word, I need to pass ImageView with Picture to another Fragment screen. 
I try to use this source code to pass ImageView between first and second Activity: https://github.com/REC-LABS/REC_Photo_Editor
Thank you a lot!

Comment: you could have done a simple google search to find lots of result of passing variables. transferring one view to from one activity view to another fragment view isnt possible. you need to recreate the imageview and just use the image from the activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass object between activity and fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279690/how-to-pass-object-between-activity-and-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Create a construction in fragment and while attaching that fragment add ImageView as its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you need to recreate the imageview and just use the image from the activity. 
Create a parcelable, simply to pass in intent/Bundle as normal object, get it in your fragment/Activity