# Fragment stack: push/pop Fragments from top fragment

Tags: android, stack, fragment

Support4Demos feature Fragment stacks... but conveniently place the pop/push CountingFragment controls outside of the stack (all takes place in one layout, but the push/pop buttons are below, still in the Fragment that holds the whole layout.

**How** can the controls be made to work from the top fragment?

[EDIT]
Another way to look at it:
I want to make Fragments on a stack behave like Activities, each can pop itself, or launch another.
How would you alter the "FragmentStack" example from Support4Demos so that the "Go home"/"Add new"/"Pop top" buttons are in the CountingFragments, rather than in FragmentStackSupport which holds the FragmentManager?
A reasonable design - consider "CountingFragments" containing clickable ListViews?

How to do that? Ideally, each stack Fragment would hold a reference to the "stack holder' Fragment, or its (Child)FragmentManager. Those, however, are not Parcelable, and [Fragment constructors must not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798489/proper-way-to-give-initial-data-to-fragments) (though *everything else* works great when I do it). Holding a reference to that is also bad, since the "stack holder' Fragment, too, can be destroyed and recreated.


[EDIT2]
All right, here are some ideas I came up with.

- For "go home" and "pop top", I suppose I could add those (invisible) buttons to the hosting Fragment, and then access them in the hosted Fragments via `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById` or somesuch.
  That's ugly enough. But pushing new ones? Only related thing I can think of is adding a custom View class into the hosting layout, that holds a reference to the FragmentManager, to be grabbed by the hosted Fragments.
- holding references to the FragmentManager(s) in a static map somewhere
- register a BroadcastReceiver in the hosting Fragment, send broadcasts with data from the hosted ones, telling it what to do. But the host Fragment shouldn't have to babysit its children.
- Have each stacked Fragment itself be host to either its true content, or the next stacked Fragment. That way, there is always a FragmentManager at hand (except for popping), but 2 fragments are needed per page, not to mention the weirdness of it all.

Please tell me there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ChristopherPerry I've added more info. I hope someone more knowledgeable can give a better solution, or at least tell me what to go with