# How to parse value from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: java, android

How to pass value from Activity to Fragment?
I hope someone can help.

Comment: Add code that you have try

Comment: Can you add a little more description? and what have you tried?

Comment: This is another post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726834/how-to-change-pages-in-viewpager-with-different-content This is my problem.

Comment: do you mean `pass` or `parse`??  add code which you have already tried

Comment: This is another post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726834/how-to-change-pages-in-viewpager-with-different-content This is my problem. I want to get value from activity and set in the fragment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to give initial data to fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798489/proper-way-to-give-initial-data-to-fragments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "From Activity");
//set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      String strtext=getArguments().getString("name");

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: this returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: create a constrater on fragment and get data in constrater object